# Server Error in tag Application can't load master page tag

Tags: visual-studio-2010, master-pages

I have this error and i don't know how to fix it, the master page is there and linked properly:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
```

Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: The file '/AEDMasterPage.master' does not exist.

Source Error:

Line 1:  <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/AEDMasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
Line 2:
Line 3:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
_Default
```

to

```
Default
```

and make sure path of master file is correct
this is the simple error that file path is not valid